# Make a radio button check based on condition

Tags: html, visual-studio, checkbox, radio-button

When values are submitted I want all entries to be as they were when submitted by the user. Don't know how to do this for radio buttons and checkboxes.

```
    <input type="text" name="text" value="@Request.Form["text"]" placeholder="Enter text"/>

    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="Male" value="Male" />
    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="Female" value="Female" /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit text"/>
```

Comment: Tell me if my answer worked for you :D

Answer (score 0):

In your javascript use the jQuery library.

Upon the results, you can have variables changing (for example `var checked = true` or `false`). Then upon that result use an if statement like:

```
if (checked === true) {
 $('elementID').attr(checked);
}
else {
 $('elementID').attr();
}
```

This should work for both radio and checkboxes.

Comment: I don't think there is a different method of doing this. Unless you use javascript I don't think this is possible. I suggest learning javascript and jquery library as they will be very useful.